# How do I make my task assignment associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, model-associations

I have a User model, a TodoList model, which has many todoItems. My models are :

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable

has_many :todo_lists
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
   :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

**TodoList Model**

```
class TodoList < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :todo_items
belongs_to :user
end
```

**ToItem Model**

```
class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
include AASM
belongs_to :todo_list
def completed?
!completed_at.blank?
end
#belongs_to :user
#belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: 'friend_id'    
aasm :column => 'state', :whiny_transitions => false do
    state :not_assigned, :initial => true
    state :assigned
    state :taskCompleted
end
```

I am trying to modify my models in such that any user can request to be assigned a taskItem and the user whom the task belongs to can accept or deny the requests. Once a an assignment request is approved, I want the task to be also associated to the user assigned to it.
How do I go about that with my model associations and relationships ? Thanks in advance for the help .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `assignments` association table, in a many-to-many relationship between User and TodoItem. Your association table would have an additional boolean attribute, indicating whether the item owner has accepted the request. Something like:

```
class TodoItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :users, through: :assignments
  ...
end
```

For `User`:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :todo_items, through: :assignments
  ...
end
```

And finally the association table:

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :todo_item
end
```

Your migration to create the association table would be something like this:

```
class CreateAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :assignments do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :todo_item, index: true
      t.boolean :request_accepted, default: false, null: false
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```